# Bluetooth headphones forcing fallback

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I'm having a weird problem but the solution is probably easy and going over my head. I'm using a pair of Sony WH-XB900N over bluetooth, when I connect them for audio only everything works fine, but if I try to use any form of input it always ends up looping the mic to my headphones.

My laptop has a mic, but when I connect the headphones over bluetooth that input option disappears. I tried tinkering with some alsa settings and nothing changed, in pavucontrol the only input listed is the headset microphone and it has the "set as fallback" button selected, if I try do deselect it "doesn't accept", changing back to selected automatically. I also went in pulse-audio preferences and deselected the allow multiple devices.

I checked for updates, force stopped alsa and pulse-audio, tried rebooting, looking into bluetooth manager and had no luck.

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, it's the 20.04